# WPF dynamic layout using user config file

Tags: c#, wpf, config

I have an application that receives IoT data. I would like to change the layout (that displays the data) depending on the configuration set by the user.

Eg: The user decides that 3 bytes will be device_id, 4th byte when multiplied by a value gives temperature value,etc. How can I create such a user config file and save it for later use ?

After saving the data, how can I display the data based on these config files? I am thinking of using labels to just match the data. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: [Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) is one of the ways to achieve what you require!

Comment: @Nobody but how can I take value from the user for the config file ?

Answer (score 0):

So I have done as @Nobody suggested.

I have created a class with details like number of bytes, device id, etc and then took the data from user input via a form. Later used Basic Serialization to save the data and deserialization to read it back the next time I open the Application as per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/walkthrough-persisting-an-object-in-visual-studio).

Code :

```
[Serializable()]
public class Config
{
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }

}

using (Stream testFileStream = File.Create(pathString)) // Serialization code
{
    BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    serializer.Serialize(testFileStream, config);
    testFileStream.Close();
}

using (Stream testFileStream = File.OpenRead(pathString))
{
    BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    config = (Config)deserializer.Deserialize(testFileStream);
    testFileStream.Close();
}
```